# i need a jquery command to change background-image: url() content

Tags: jquery

i an a newbie. i have this code:

```
<div id="cloud-zoom-big" class="cloud-zoom-big" style="position: absolute; left: 342px; top: -10px; width: 390px; height: 390px; background-image: url(http://kato-shoes.ro/image/cache/data/balerini/balerini1234verde-750x750.jpg); z-index: 99; background-position: -359px -359px;">
    <div class="cloud-zoom-title" style="opacity: 0.5;">Balerini Prada 1234</div>
</div>
```

i need a jquery command that changes the **background-image: url()** content(what is inside () ),  with another link. this another link is something like this ('href'.data.data.pop)

here is the line with comment that should be changed:

Image swapping for variant

```
if(data.data.image !='')  {

$('#image').attr('src', data.data.thumb);
$('#wrap a').attr('href', data.data.pop);
$('.image a').attr('href', data.data.pop);  // this line to be fixed
                       }
```

HOW should the bold line look like?
can someone please help, i am stuck in this for 3 weeks... :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
var imageUrl = data.data.pop;
$('#image').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: the url still does not change in HTML code.
i posted my problem here:forum.welfordmedia.co.uk/discussion/36/image-big-zoom-malfunction#Item_3

Comment: i do not have any background-image: in the stylesheet.css .cloud-zoom-big class